# Restore cancelled order in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to restore order that have been cancelled.i'm having problems restoring cancelled-orders and recovering purchase request from order view page.is there any extension which can help me resolve this problem?

Comment: You can try this one https://marketplace.magento.com/addify-uncancel.html

Answer (score 2):

And if you want try to restore cancelled order by specific order id, you can try with below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load(162); //162 is your order id

$order->setState("processing")
    ->setStatus("processing")
    ->save();

$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
    $item->setData("qty_canceled",0)->save();
}
```

Hope this solution will help you!